# Angular HttpClient post read headers from empty response

Tags: json, angular, rest, jwt

I'm trying to build my authentication on JWT. I'm using Spring filters to achieve that goal, and i'm returning positive (200) response with one header (Authorization) on successfull login. Unfortunately i'm still getting JSON parse problem from my Angular client.

Client code:

```
this.http.post<HttpResponse<void>>(EndPoint.LOGIN,
  {'username': username, 'password': password } ,
  {'headers' : new HttpHeaders ({'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'responseType': 'text'})})
.subscribe(response => console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization')))
  ;
```

Response:

```
authorization →Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJHZXJhbHQiLCJleHAiOjE1MjAwNTk4MzN9.813r4QmVgrnrsm4HwZID1M56hD42PLe0BvbCu-bQoQWSnxllOE0iAjS-fc-BI8R8eGGE0WPSSL0OaKxz2lxDjA
content-length →0
```

Error:

```
message : "Unexpected end of JSON input"
```

It is working like a charm from REST client like Postman.

I was trying multiple things to get this done:

- set responseType to text
- add something to response body (error has changed - it can't parse first letter of new response body)
- posting without generic HttpResponse object

No luck for now.

Answer (score 2):

responseType is not a http header, but just an options for the http request

You also need to specify `observe: response` if you want to be able to retrieve the header

https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Try that

```
this.http.post(EndPoint.LOGIN,
  {'username': username, 'password': password } ,
  {'headers' : new HttpHeaders ({'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}), 'responseType': 'text', observe:'response'})
.subscribe((response : any) => console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization')))
  ;
```